# Ler colunas exatas csv php

Tags: php, csv

Estou lendo o csv desta forma:

```
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {
        if($row !== 0)
        {
            $dados      = explode(";", $data[0]);
            $VALOR_1        = utf8_encode($dados[1]);
            $VALOR_2        = $dados[2];
            $VALOR_3        = $dados[3];
            $VALOR_4        = $dados[4];
            $VALOR_6        = $dados[11];

                $insert = "
                    INSERT INTO
                        dados
                    VALUES
                    (
                        NULL,
                        '$VALOR_1',
                        '$VALOR_2',
                        '$VALOR_3',
                        '$VALOR_4',
                        '$VALOR_6',
                    )
                ";
                    //$insert_now = mysqli_query($mysqli, $insert);
        }
    }
```

A primeira linha do csv contem o título de cada coluna, o csv possuí várias colunas, o problema é que as colunas nem sempre estão posicionadas no mesmo local.
O que preciso é ler o csv, e já deixar informado o título das colunas a serem salvas no bd.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o exemplo do `csv`, porque pelo visto o resto já está feito. e para entender melhor a sua duvida precisa de algum exemplo

Comment: No arquivo `csv` tem um separador de colunas, que no seu exemplo é o `;`, isso não está funcionando?

Comment: Você precisa identificar as colunas na tabela! também com é essa tabela que precisa gravar resultados!?

Comment: Mas se esta usando fgetcsv pra que então usar explode? Não tem necessidade disto. Diga-me, qual separador o teu csv usa, é virgula ou ponto-virgula?

Answer (score -3):

Tente atribuir a uma variável o índice da coluna, dai é independente o posicionamento da mesma...

Exemplo:

```
$fieldnames = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',');
$idx_dado_5 = array_search("dado_5", $fieldnames);
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle , 4096, ',')) {

        $valor_5 = $row[$idx_dado_5];
$insert = "
                INSERT INTO
                    dados
                VALUES
                (
                    NULL,
                    '$VALOR_1',
                    '$VALOR_2',
                    '$VALOR_3',
                    '$VALOR_4',
                    '$VALOR_5',
                )
            ";
}
```